# Python implementing abstract stack

Tags: python, data-structures, stack, python-3.6

I'm trying to implement a stack without using Python's in-built stack/queue methods to understand the logic. Could someone please resolve the error below and provide a working solution - i think I'm close.

```
data = ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")

stackArray = []
stackPointer = 0
stackMaximum = 7

#Routine to Push
if stackPointer < stackMaximum:
    stackPointer = stackPointer + 1
    stackArray[stackPointer] = data
else:
    print("Stack Full")

#Routine to pop
if stackPointer > 0:
    stackPointer = stackPointer - 1
    stackArray[stackPointer] = data
else:
    print("No data to pop off")
```

stackArray[stackPointer] = data
NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: Where did you *expect* `data` to come from?

Comment: Had the wrong variable name. Corrected now.

Comment: So do you still get the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class stack(object):
    def __init__(self, maxsize = None):
     self.stackArrayList = []  #You can use list to implement the stack
     self.maxsize = maxsize

    def isEmpty(self):
     return self.size() == 0 #Checks if the stackArrayList is Empty.

    def push(self, item):
        if len(self.stackArrayList) >= self.maxsize:
            raise Exception("Stack is Full")
        return self.stackArrayList.append(item)  #Append new element to the stackArrayList.

    def pop(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            raise Exception("Stack empty!")
        return self.stackArrayList.pop()#Pop and return the top element of the stackArrayList.

    def peek(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            raise Exception("Stack empty!")
        return self.stackArrayList[-1]  #Returns the value of top element in the stackArrayList

    def size(self):
        return len(self.stackArrayList)  #Returns the size of stackArrayList

    def show(self):
        return self.stackArrayList #Returns the contents of the stackArrayList


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Please note that your input is a tuple
    data = ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
    stackArray = stack(maxsize = 7)
    for var in data:
        stackArray.push(var)
    print(stackArray.pop())
    print(stackArray.show())
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is of the type `tuple`. When you are assigning it to the stackArray, it will give you `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Refer to the https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-data-structure-introduction-program/ and select your language as Python for more details.